# Why this regex does not accept zero?

Tags: regex

I have this regular expression:

```
(1*+0)
```

I tested it Regex Buddy's Test module, and it highlighted these:

[image: regular expression: 1*+0]

It does not recognize the string: *0*, neither *1001*, &c.

Why the zero (0) character is not considered?

Thanks in advance!

N.B.: I tested the same regex and the same data in Notepad++, but it does work, too.

Comment: Maybe a program bug? Never heard of that Regex Buddy's.

Comment: @m0skit0 Official web site: http://www.regexbuddy.com/ I tested the regex in Notepad++, too.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to match? Any line containing 0 and/or 1, regardless of amount?

Comment: But you're using a different regex in regexbuddy. You mentioned `1*+0` but used `(1*|0)`, there's a difference. In any case, could you show a bit more of your screen? There might be some settings that are relevant.

Comment: After some testing, this behaviour is language dependent. Try on GNU ERE and it will not ignore the 0. As of why, I'm not entirely sure yet.

Comment: @Jerry I have been using Perl regex engine in Regex Buddy.

Comment: @JohnOrtizOrdoñez Well, I don't get that [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6tNNq.png) (v4.0.3).

Answer (score 1):

What is the regex you're testing? `1*+0` or `(1*|0)`?

The first one, depending on the regex syntax you're considering, might contain an error `*` followed by `+`.

The second one matches **zero or more occurrences of 1** or 0, since there are always at least zero occurrences of 1 the first part is always matched.

If you want all lines containing one or more 1 or one 0: `^(1+|0)$`

Comment: That's no error. It's called a possessive quantifier.

Comment: That's a little better, but I'd remove the 'error' part completely.

Comment: @Jerry I don't see why. i.e. if you try `*+` in Javascript all you get is an Exception.

Comment: @pNre That regex works(no error) with `Ruby`, `Java`, and `PHP` and not with `Python`, `Perl`, `Javascript` as I tested!